# taking the data from database showing to combo box but the value member is different

Tags: sql, vb.net

i am taking the data from database and showing to combo box , i want to see the name but the original value is id..  i have one code here, please review it what i did the wrong here. 
Public Sub nameshow()

```
    Try
        'declare variables


        Dim objDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim objDataAdapter1 As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim objDataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim objDataSet1 As New DataSet()



        '//state dataset of combo box
        ' Set the SelectCommand properties...
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = sql.SqlConn
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from tblBrand"
        objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        '//mention the second data 
        objdataadapter1.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
        objDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.Connection = sql.SqlConn
        objDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from tblModel"
        objDataAdapter1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        ' Open the database connection...
        sql.SqlConn.Open()
        ' Fill the DataSet object with data...
        objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "tblBrand")
        objDataAdapter1.Fill(objDataSet1, "tblModel")
        ' Close the database connection...
        sql.SqlConn.Close()

        With (cboxBrandName)
            .DataSource = objDataSet
            .ValueMember = "tblBrand.BandID"
            .DisplayMember = "tblBrand.BrandName"
        End With
        With (cboxModel)
            .DataSource = objDataSet1
            .ValueMember = "tblModel.ModelID"
            .DisplayMember = "tblModel.ModelName"
        End With

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

after run the program nothing showing into the combo box. i dont understand why, and there is no error too.
i am calling this function in form load. 
thanks....

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think happens after studying it a bit more:

You are getting an error. Most likely "Connection is already open." Then this error is swallowed by you try catch statement. Thus never reaching the adding of the datasource to the combobox. Try this instead:

```
Public Function SelectRows( _
    ByVal dataSet As DataSet, ByVal connectionString As String, _
    ByVal queryString As String) As DataSet

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand( _
            queryString, connection)
        adapter.Fill(dataSet)
        Return dataSet
    End Using 
End Function
```

Call it with this:

```
objDataSet = SelectRows(objDataSet, "ConnectionString","select * from tblBrand")
With (cboxBrandName)
    .DataSource = objDataSet
    .ValueMember = "tblBrand.BandID"
    .DisplayMember = "tblBrand.BrandName"
End With
```

I do believe this will work.

Comment: class system.data.dataset cannot indexed because it has no default property... this is the error now showing, not accept line "DataSource = objDataSet("tblBrand")"

Comment: i forget the tables, its running now, but still the same, no rows in combo box. please check again.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get an error? Because you are swallowing it with your Try Catch statement. I'll update my answer in a bit.

Comment: what you gave thats not running. thats showing error.

Comment: Did you change the value of ConnectionString? This code is from MSDN so I would be surprised if it did not work.